# Why does changing an object you've already pushed to an array change the value in the array as well?

Tags: javascript, arrays

check this code:

```
var bbb = [];
var aaa = {};

aaa.test = "1";
bbb.push(aaa);
console.log(bbb[0].test);

aaa.test = "2";
bbb.push(aaa);
console.log(bbb[0].test);
```

Why the console ouput is "1,2"? I think it should be "1,1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are added to the array by reference. So, when you do `bbb[0]`, it is referring to the instance of `aaa` that you created previously and then modified.

If you don't want this behavior, you need to clone the object before adding it.

`bbb.push(clone(aaa))`

As for the implementation of `clone()`, if you have jQuery :

```
function clone(obj) {
  return jQuery.extend({}, obj);
}
```

And without jQuery:

```
function clone(obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FzqZr/)**

Comment: how can i make the console output to "1,1"?

Answer (score 0):

Your passing a reference of `aaa` to the array.  So when you make a change to `aaa` it is reflected in the first element of the array.